# Javascript - One line if statement

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, ecmascript-6

I'm still getting used to the best practices for Javascript. I would like to know what would be the best way to shorten the following if statement, possibly even in one line. How would I go about that?

```
onSelect: function (sortOption) {
      this.activeOption = option;
      if (option.value === null) {
        this.tableData = this.$props.trashList;
      } else {
        this.tableData = this.$props.trashList.filter(item => item.isToggle === option.value);
      }
    },
```

Comment: Shorter doesn't necessarily mean better: in this case, you are short circuiting the filter logic before it happens. If you are to use a one-liner, you will have to move the null check into the filter callback, which means you'll be performing unnecessary filtering.

Comment: If code is easy to read then, generally, it is easier to understand and easier to maintain by your future self and your colleagues. Strive for readability first and other benefits come naturally. Obviously, readability is subjective, so do what make sense for your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
onSelect: function(sortOption) {
    this.activeOption = option;
    this.tableData = option.value === null
        ? this.$props.trashList;
        : this.$props.trashList.filter(item => item.isToggle === option.value);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this is really better, but you can do this:

```
onSelect: function (sortOption) {
      this.activeOption = option;
      
        this.tableData = this.$props.trashList.filter(item => option.value === null || item.isToggle === option.value);
      
    },
```

Comment: I think OP already have better choice . In your code you are `unnecessarily` running the loop on first condition . And filter loop always running upto end of index.

Answer (score 0):

You choice  was Good and better. I going to simplified with `ternary operator`

```
this.tableData = option.value ? this.$props.trashList : this.$props.trashList.filter(item => item.isToggle === option.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onSelect: function (sortOption) {
  this.activeOption = option;
 this.tableData = option.value ? this.$props.trashList.filter(item => item.isToggle === option.value) : this.$props.trashList;
}
```